# Cross-compilation of ROS2 Humble for Raspberry PI

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to cross-compile ROS2 Humble itself for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

My board is not new, it has 32-bit CPU and 1Gb of RAM.
I have installed Ubuntu 22.10 server on it.

I have failed to find binary ROS2 packages for it and now trying to build them from source.

However, building on the Raspberry directly often fails, because a compiler exhausts RAM and OS kills it.
I have installed ros_cross_compile tool and now trying to cross-compile ROS2 on my laptop.
However, this tool tries to download packages instead of building them and fails.

Commands

```
mkdir -p ros2_humble/src
cd  ros2_humble
vcs import --input https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/humble/ros2.repos src    
ros_cross_compile . --arch armhf --os ubuntu --rosdistro humble
```

Here is the tail of their output

```
INFO:Docker Client:+ apt-get install -y cmake acl libacl1-dev libatomic1 python3-pytest python3-dev ros-humble-mimick-vendor libconsole-bridge-dev libeigen3-dev git uncrustify doxygen libignition-cmake2-dev libopencv-dev ros-humble-fastcdr libssl-dev libtinyxml2-dev libasio-dev libtinyxml-dev python3-numpy python3-yaml python3-pytest-timeout qtbase5-dev libspdlog-dev python3-pycodestyle python3-catkin-pkg-modules python3-empy python3-pkg-resources python3-minimal ros-humble-orocos-kdl-vendor libqt5core5a libqt5gui5 qt5-qmake libbenchmark-dev libqt5opengl5 libqt5widgets5 ros-humble-laser-geometry ros-humble-cv-bridge python3-mypy python3-pytest-mock libassimp-dev python3-importlib-metadata ros-humble-urdfdom-headers libfreetype6 libx11-dev libxaw7-dev libxrandr-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev pkg-config libfreetype6-dev python3-flake8 python3-lark libxml2-utils python3-psutil python3-rosdistro-modules openssl libcunit1-devros-humble-kdl-parser libsqlite3-dev python3-setuptools python3-argcomplete python3-netifaces python3-packaging graphviz libgtest-dev rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 pydocstyle clang-tidy python3-babeltrace libbullet-dev pyflakes3 python3-lxml python3-cryptography libzstd-dev libignition-math6-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev curl file pybind11-dev python3-nose clang-format libyaml-dev python3-pytest-cov google-mock python3-lttng cppcheck ros-humble-urdfdom libyaml-cpp-dev

INFO:Docker Client:Reading package lists...
INFO:Docker Client:Building dependency tree...
INFO:Docker Client:Reading state information...
INFO:Docker Client:E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-mimick-vendor
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-fastcdr
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-orocos-kdl-vendor
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-laser-geometry
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-cv-bridge

INFO:Docker Client:E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-urdfdom-headers
E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-kdl-parser

INFO:Docker Client:E: Unable to locate package ros-humble-urdfdom
```

It tries to install the packages with `apt` instead of building them.

This command is written in the file `cc_internals/armhf-ubuntu-humble/install_rosdeps.sh`. I've tried to edit it, however, ros_cross_compile tool overwrites it, and I cannot find how to make it to use my own file instead of generating it.

I have tried to submit my customized `install_rosdeps.sh` with `--custom-rosdep-script`  flag, but it didn't help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412639/cross-compilation-of-ros2-humble-for-raspberry-pi/) by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2023-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if you are running out of RAM building it natively on the pi you can set up a swapfile on the sd card (a standard linux technique not ros specific to use persistent storage as additional RAM - it will be slow but it should enable to the process to complete

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2023-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wl](https://answers.ros.org/users/68917/wl/) on 2023-02-19**:
Thank you, it worked! Build of rclcpp took 73min, but it has finished, at least!